# Bundle native JNI shared libraries with Clojure libraries

Tags: java, clojure, java-native-interface, leiningen

I am writing a library for clojure which involves native code. How can I bundle the shared library (aka native dependencies) when I deploy the clojure libraries to public repositories (like clojars)?

### Further Info:

My project structure looks roughly like:

```
src/
    native/     - C code , C Object files and compiled shared libs
    java/       - Java stuff
    clojure/    - Clojure stuff
```

I am currently using leineingen. I have tried doing:

```
:jvm-opts [~(str "-Djava.library.path=src/native/:"
          (System/getenv "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))]
```

It works if I am in the project. However, if I include this project as a dependency, I will get a `UnsatisfiedLink` error.

Comment: How did you add the native library project to other projects' dependencies?

Comment: I used lein's checkout dependencies https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on your exact use-case. In the simplest situation, you need to:

- bundle the native lib inside the library jar, for example by including the `native/` folder in `:resource-paths` in your `project.clj`.
- when you use your library, you can specify a `:native-prefix` option to indicate a path inside your library jar from which native libraries should be extracted. For example, if your library contains a resource "mylib.so" in the root folder, you can specify it like this: `[com.foo/bar "1.0.1" :native-prefix ""]`
- you should also specify where the extracted libs should go, using the `:native-path` option in your `project.clj`.
- finally, you should add the `:native-path` you have specified to `java.library.path`, using `:jvm-opts` like you said.

These options are documented in the [sample leiningen project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj).

Now the reason I said it depends on your use-case is that if you want to create an uberjar that contains native libs, things start getting more messy. The main reason is that you can't directly link to a lib that is zipped inside your jar. If you're lucky, you'll be able to use the `loadLibraryFromJar` method in the [NativeUtils](https://github.com/adamheinrich/native-utils/blob/master/NativeUtils.java) class. However, I remember having `ClassLoader`-related issues that prevented me from using `System/load`. Instead I had to make sure the library was present in one of the paths that the JVM looks for, so that `System/loadLibrary` finds it correctly. Here is what I ended up doing:

- manually extract the native lib from the uberjar at runtime to a temporary folder, with `(-> my-lib io/resource io/input-stream (io/copy my-temp-file))`
- update the `java.library.path` system property at runtime to add the temporary folder to it, using `System/setProperty`
- finally, use [this reflection trick](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.fr/2011/08/changing-java-library-path-at-runtime.html) to force the library path to be updated

This is painful to setup, but after that it works pretty well.